# C# - Terminating Application.Run()

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading

Is there a way to cleanly terminate a message loop issued by calling `System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run()` from another thread?

```
Thread messageLoop = new Thread(() => Application.Run());
messageLoop.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
messageLoop.Start();
//How to terminate thread like on Application.ExitThread() without calling Thread.Abort()?
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the ApplicationContext class to keep a reference to the thread.  Like this:

```
    ApplicationContext threadContext;

    private void startLoop() {
        threadContext = new ApplicationContext();
        var messageLoop = new Thread(() => Application.Run(threadContext));
        messageLoop.Start();
    }

    private void stopLoop() {
        threadContext.ExitThread();
        threadContext = null;
    }
```